# Interpreting a function as having multiple types

Tags: haskell, typeclass

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
data X = I Int | D Double deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

{-
-- A normal declaration which works fine
instance Num X where
  (I a) + (I b) = I $ a + b
  (D a) + (D b) = D $ a + b
  -- ...   
-}                                          

coerce :: Num a => X -> X -> (a -> a -> a) -> X
coerce (I a) (I b) op = I $ a `op` b
coerce (D a) (D b) op = D $ a `op` b

instance Num X where
  a + b = coerce a b (+)
```

When compiling I get an error:

```
 tc.hs:18:29:
     Couldn't match type `Double' with `Int'
     In the second argument of `($)', namely `a `op` b'
     In the expression: I $ a `op` b
     In an equation for `coerce': coerce (I a) (I b) op = I $ a `op` b
```

In `coerce` I'd like to interpret `op` as both `Int -> Int -> Int` and `Double -> Double -> Double`. I think I should be able to do this because op is of type `Num a => a -> a -> a`.

My main goal is to abstract away the repetition needed in the functioning Num subclass: I'd much rather write it like I did in the uncommented version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your definition of coerce restricts type of op to `Int -> Int -> Int` by first definition and `Double -> Double -> Double` by second. If you really want to say that `op` is polymorphic in a for all `Num` class then you should use `Rank2Types` to make it work.

```
coerce :: X -> X -> (forall a . Num a => a -> a -> a) -> X
coerce (I a) (I b) op = I $ a `op` b
coerce (D a) (D b) op = D $ a `op` b
coerce (I a) (D b) op = D $ op (fromIntegral a) b
coerce (D a) (I b) op = D $ op a (fromIntegral b)
```

Comment: The `Rank2Types` extension is now being deprecated, one should use `RankNTypes`. (`Rank2Types` doesn't/didn't guarantee that only rank 2 types are used, it would also let higher rank types be used. I'm not sure whether `Rank2Types` is kept as a synonym for `RankNTypes`, I think the decision was against it.)